# Changing play.tmp in Play! Framework don't change upload default folder

Tags: java, upload, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to change the default folder to where my uploaded files go. In my **application.conf** I set **play.tmp=/my/desired/location/** but when I upload the file it always go to the default folder which is, according to Play! documentation, **/tmp/**.

I'm using play 2.2.2 built with Scala 2.10.3 (running Java 1.8.0)

Upload controller:

```
public static Result uploadFile() {
    MultipartFormData body = request().body().asMultipartFormData();
    FilePart audioFile = body.getFile(Constants.KEY_UPLOAD_AUDIO_FILE);
    if (audioFile != null) {
        String fileName = audioFile.getFilename();
        String contentType = audioFile.getContentType();
        File file = audioFile.getFile();
        return ok("File uploaded to: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
    } else {
        return badRequest("File not found");
    }
}
```

Thank you all for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common approach after upload is moving file from `tmp` folder to destination folder, preferably placed in your `application.conf`, i.e.:

```
upload.path = "/my/desired/location/"
```

So right before your `return` you can just move it to correct place:

```
String uploadPath = Play.application().configuration().getString("upload.path", "/tmp/");
file.renameTo(uploadPath + fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I already tried that approach as suggested here:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15135850/play-2-1-java-complete-basic-file-upload-solution], and I'de like to avoid **Apache commons**. I was wondering why the **play.tmp=/my/desired/location/** don't work as it's supposed to work, or if I'm missing some detail.

Comment: 1) Apache commons are delivered to you with Play, 2) anyway... `renameTo` method IS NOT `commons` part it's from `Java.io.File` API, 3) sorry, don't know why `play.tmp` config doesn't work

Comment: Yes, in my case, due to the fact that I have **/my/desired/location/** in a different partition, I need to use **Apache Commons**, well no problem. Thank you.